# Consider $f(x) =3x^2+2x+a$ where a is parameter such that $\frac{da}{dt}=3$ Let $a =0$, when $t =0$ and....

Tags: calculus, integration

Problem :

Consider $f(x) =3x^2+2x+a$ where a is parameter such that $\frac{da}{dt}=3$ Let $a =0$, when $t =0$ and $A(t) =\int^t_0 \{f(x)\}\,dx$ ( where $\{\cdot\}$ denotes the fractional part function ). If $A(2)$ can be expressed as sum of $n$ integrals then find the minimum value of $n$.

My approach :

$$\frac{da}{dt}=3$$

Integrating both sides we get :

$$a =3t +c $$

Please suggest how to proceed further will be of great of help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to evaluate $c$ from the initial conditions.  Then I believe you are expected to write $\{f(x)\}=f(x)-\lfloor f(x) \rfloor$ and write your integral as $A(2) =\int^2_0 \{f(x)\}dx=\int_0^{b_1}(f(x)-d)dx+\int_{b_1}^{b_2}(f(x)-(d+1))dx+\dots \int_{b_{n-1}}^2(f(x)-(d+n-1))dx$
where you choose the $b_i$ to be the points where $f(x)$ goes through an integer and $d=\lfloor f(0)\rfloor$.  Note that the $t$ that is part of the definition of $f(x)$ is specified by the argument of $A$, so it does not vary during the integral.

Added:  the initial condition says $c=0$, so $A(2)=\int_0^2 \{3x^2+2x+6\}\; dx$.  This is plugging in your first comment.  Now what is the range of $f(x)$ over the domain $[0,2]?$  That goes into my original answer.

Comment: Putting t =0 , a =0 we get c =0 What does this means :

Comment: A(2) = $\int^2_0 \{f(x)\}dx $ at t =2 a = 6

Comment: Answer is we require 16 integral to expressed as a sum please elaborate how we can conclude to this answer , it will be of great help thanks.